# dotenv and linked_files with capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Having a really hard time getting this to work. I just added [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)  to accommodate for the Rails 4.1 secrets.yml file. I also have in the `.env` file the database.yml's password.

To add to my deploy:

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml .env}
```

When I run `cap production deploy` I get:

```
/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on 107.170.....
```

How can I get the database.yml to be added?

I looked at the [capistrano touch gem](https://github.com/rjocoleman/capistrano-touch-linked-files) with no luck because after I create the empty files, ActiveRecord throws an error of `No 'production' database`

Comment: where you keep `database.yml` and `.env`? on local machine?

Comment: `config/database.yml` and `.env` is in the root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create task for upload your `.env` and `database.yml`.Look example below:

```
desc "Database config"
  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
  # upload you database.yml from config dir to shared dir on server
  put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
  # make symlink
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  # upload you database.yml from config dir to shared dir on server
  put File.read(".env"), "#{shared_path}/config/.env"
  # make symlink
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/.env #{current_path}/.env"
end
```

And add `before` and `after` hooks.

Or use [`dotenv-deployment`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv-deployment) that contain the same tasks.

Comment: I am using dotenv-deployment but it's not working with me. On first deploy, I keep getting `ERRORlinked file /home/joggle/joggle_extension_backend/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on 107.170....`

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy this mean on server have no `database.yml` file.

Comment: Yes, the server is a fresh server. So I need to somehow get the database.yml file in the shared path. Let me try your way

Comment: check my listing, this puts database.yml from your project dir to shared server dir